# How to program Attiny12 with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny

I bought a bunch of Attiny12's from Digikey without checking if I can even program them with an Arduino. I've looked around a bunch, and I've only ever found ways to program Attiny13 and Attiny10.

Strangely, one of the board packages I downloaded had board information for the Attiny12 in the avrdude.conf file, but I can't select it in the Arduino IDE. I've tried to change the Attiny13 info in the config file to the Attin12 and just selecting the Attiny13, but I'm getting the following error:

```
         Using Port                    : COM3
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATtiny13
         Chip Erase delay              : 20000 us
         PAGEL                         : P00
         BS2                           : P00
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom         4     8    64    0 no         64    0      0  9000 20000 0xff 0xff
           flash          4     5   128    0 no       1024    0      0  4500 20000 0xff 0xff
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.03s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Error while burning bootloader.
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.03s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.
```

Anyway I can program the Attiny12 without resorting to a dedicated programmer?

Comment: are you asking about programming with `Arduino` or with `Arduino IDE`?

Comment: info about programming is almost non-existent ... maybe info here can be used to write a programming sketch ... http://web.archive.org/web/20090823113448/http://www.xs4all.nl:80/~sbolt/e-spider_prog.html

Comment: here is the datasheet for Attiny12 ... it's the 94 page one labeled `ATtiny11/12` ... https://web.archive.org/web/20090417081256/http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/alldatasheets.asp?family_id=607

Comment: LOL. Well, in some ways I love the question, but you're not going to run an Arduino sketch on this thing. And it's for the same reason. The ATTiny12 has no RAM. I don't mean little RAM, I mean **literally no RAM** and no way to add RAM to its internal address space. Basically, all you have inside the chip for mutable state is the general purpose registers and whatever peripheral registers you can cram stuff into. gcc/g++ do not support it as a C or C++ target. So, if you want to know about ardunoisp.ino to program an assembly program, okay. But, you're not going to code this chip with Arduino.

Comment: @timemage Huh, I completely missed that. So what's the purpose of this microcontroller?

Comment: Whatever purpose you can dream up with assembly code. It is theoretically possible to make C run on such a thing with extraordinary limitations that might technically violate even the non-hosted standard. But, gcc does not do this. The attiny13 is very similar but has *some* RAM and can be coded be coded via an Arduino core in a very limited way. If you want to stick with this tiny series, use the the ATTiny85, but really, still don't exactly recommend it. If you're new to all this stuff, you really should not go smaller the an Arduino UNO/Nano/Promini in terms of memories.

Comment: If "program Attiny12 with Arduino" was intended to mean, "use an Ardunio board to put code onto a Attiny12", then your question in still unanswered and on topic (so far as I'm concerned anyway) though may need clarification.  If it was intended to mean "use Arduino code/core/ecosystem *on* an Attiny12" then it's basically answered. You can delete the question or you can clarify in the question that that's what you meant and I'll convent the essence of the comment into an answer.

Comment: @timemage The former - I wanted to use an Arduino Uno as a programmer for Attiny, so I don't have to buy a dedicated programmer.